# how to retrieve data from db for registation on laravel?

Tags: laravel-5

how to retrieve data from db for registation on laravel?
I have two tables database, users and kode_instansi, I want to continue at the time of registration there is a form select that displays all data from the table kode_instansi. help master

Controller:

[image: Controller]

View:
[image: View]

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO! Whenever there's a need to input image, please post images, not links to images. However, when your images are screenshots of code, you should copy and paste the code into question body, not the screenshots. Please do that.

Comment: Start for the docs.

Answer (score 0):

Please follow the official documentation of [laravel5](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/queries). This page will clearly help you in retrieving results from DB.

The page clearly explains the different ways to retrieve data:

> Retrieving All Rows From A Table
>
> $users = DB::table('users')->get();

Here `users` is the table and this particular query would get you all the data from the users table.

Similarly,

> Retrieving A Single Row / Column From A Table
>
> $user = DB::table('users')->where('name', 'John')->first();

I would also suggest you to [configure](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/database#configuration) the database in order to use the database in laravel. Please perform this step initially.